# Cannot POST form to another php page

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, get

It should be quite simple, yet it does not work for me. I need to get user input to form and print it on another php page using GET or POST (because I think it is the easiest option and I am just building a prototype)
My default.php code:

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="pytimber.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Enter the parameter</p>
<form method="post" action="php/plot.php"> 
<input type="text" name='parameter' value="check"/>
<input type="button" value="Plot" class="homebutton" id="plot" 
onclick="plot()"/> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code:

>

```js
function plot() {
 alert('JI')
document.location.href = 'php/plot.php';
}

function goBack() {

document.location.href = '../Default.php';
}
```

Second php page code:

```
<html>
    <head>
  <script src="../pytimber.js"></script>
<?PHP
$username = $_POST["parameter"];
print ($username);
?>
    </head>
<html/>
```

Comment: When you do `document.location.href = 'php/plot.php';`, you are not posting any parameter, you are just redirecting the navigator! To POST data you have to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: Why the script? Just use a regular `submit` button and you're done. `<input type="button" ...` -> `<input type="submit" ... `

Comment: if you are directly calling the php function, why go through javascript at all? just use <input type="submit" >

Comment: You really don't need a script to post data just use a normal form and a submit button. If you really want to use javascript then you can do something as simple like this `window.open('exportToExcel.php?data='+data);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st :** Simple remove all your `javascript` .

**2nd :** Change the `button` type to `submit`

```
<input type="submit" value="Plot" name="submit" class="homebutton" id="plot" />
```

**3rd :** In second page just echo the post variable with `isset()` function

```
    if(isset( $_POST["parameter"]))
    echo $_POST["parameter"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need the js code, you just need to put a name on your button and change the type to submit and do this to another page:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["buttonname"])){
   echo $_POST["parameter"]; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by different people here, the easiest way is to utilise the awesomeness of the submit button, and let HTML take care of the rest.

But, seeing as you use javascript to 'post' the form, let me explain how that could be done as well.

By adding an id to the form, and using that to submit through js, it will work.

Change the form tag and add an id:

```
<form method="post" action="php/plot.php" id="js_form">
```

Change the plot function to this:

```
function plot() {
    alert('JI');
    document.forms["js_form"].submit();
}
```

This way the javascript will act as a submit button and send all the data to plot.php

Answer (score -1):

Either

change button type from 'button' to 'submit'

Or

change in js function 'plot'

function plot(){

document.forms[0].submit();
OR
document.getElementById('formid')'.submit;

}